# Dynamic creation of SQLite Tables in WinRT

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is it possible to create tables at runtime using SQLite for WinRT. In my application I will get list of data and its header name(column names) in the form of Json. The column name may change depends on the API request. What I am trying to create is, based on the header list I need to create the table and insert the data during runtime. Also I need to fetch this data based on demand. For all the other  table in my application is based on class model. But in the above mentioned scenario I didn’t get a solution. Is there any workaround available for this issue? If yes how I can achieve the same in my winrt application.

Comment: Are you trying to execute Create and Select Quires directly from the code? W.o using   db.CreateTable<TableName>(); &  var d = from x in db.Table<TableName>() select x;

Comment: Exactly this is what I am trying get for. May be a edit to SQLite.cs & SQLiteAsync.cs, That supports direct string query as input. But the issue is I am not a expert to edit the class..If you know please help me.